# Shrink a view based on tapping outside, without using gesture recogniser

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have three containers in my landing screen one below the other. The bottommost Container has a behaviour to increase its height based on Tap inside its bounds.

Now, once I tap anywhere on the screen - including the bounds of the said container as well as the other two containers, I want to shrink the container back to the original height.

I am currently doing this by adding a bunch of tap gesture recognisers on the other three containers and checking a boolean value (isShrunk) to do the shrinking. However these gesture recognisers seem unnecessary as all I want to do is on the next touch after the view is increased in height I want to shrink the view.

Comment: Subclass parent view and handle touch events or add gesture recognizer to parent view and resolve the parent view recognizer simultaneously with other recognizers (on child containers), fail one of another if necessary to make sure taps go through and get captured properly depending on the logic of your landing screen.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understood well your need but one way to simplify it is to refactor your code :
One parent view class with your tap gesture recognizers and your three containers as parent subclasses i.e you centralize the gesture management in one place.